# KeyboardEvent.location returns nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, jquery-events

I have thing piece of code:

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.location)
});
```

It looks like e.location returns nothing, "undefined" appears at console.
Basic task was to detect when left shift is pressed and when right one.
I went to Google and found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/location), but it doesn't work for me.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is `e.originalEvent.location` - I was doing some snooping around the `e` object and found this:

**Right Shift:**

```
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
char: undefined
charCode: 0
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: body
data: undefined
delegateTarget: body
eventPhase: 2
handleObj: Object
isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse()
jQuery21406245628797914833: true
key: undefined
keyCode: 16
metaKey: false
originalEvent: KeyboardEvent
  altKey: false
  bubbles: true
  cancelBubble: false
  cancelable: true
  charCode: 0
  ctrlKey: false
  currentTarget: null
  defaultPrevented: false
  detail: 0
  eventPhase: 0
  isTrusted: true
  isTrusted: true
  keyCode: 16
  keyIdentifier: "Shift"
  keyLocation: 2
  location: 2         // <---------------------
```

**Left Shift**

```
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
char: undefined
charCode: 0
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: body
data: undefined
delegateTarget: body
eventPhase: 2
handleObj: Object
isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse()
jQuery21406245628797914833: true
key: undefined
keyCode: 16
metaKey: false
originalEvent: KeyboardEvent
  altKey: false
  bubbles: true
  cancelBubble: false
  cancelable: true
  charCode: 0
  ctrlKey: false
  currentTarget: null
  defaultPrevented: false
  detail: 0
  eventPhase: 0
  isTrusted: true
  isTrusted: true
  keyCode: 16
  keyIdentifier: "Shift"
  keyLocation: 2
  location: 1         // <---------------------
```

Using this, you can tell which shift key is pressed since left shift has an `origanalEvent.location` of `1` and right shift has an `origanalEvent.location` of `2` and it seems like any other key has an `origanalEvent.location` of `0`.